# The trust relationship between workstation and domain fails for ASP.NET app as soon as the connection goes down

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

We have an ASP.NET app which has been installed onto a Vista laptop in order to take it offsite for a demo. The app uses Windows authentication. The problem is that the moment we disconnect the laptop from the network we get the following error:

> The trust relationship between this
>   workstation and the primary domain
>   failed.

I've seen this before when I've been screwing around with the my system clock and disconnecting from the network (which makes sense). But I can't understand why it would happen immediately the moment the network disconnects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Having seen someone report the same error on [this forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1190968.aspx). I found I was able to fix the problem by editing the web.config file and removing

```
securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
```

from the

```
<system.web>
  <sitemap>
    <providers>
      <add . . . >
```

node.